# If a suggested edit is reviewed with delete - is the edit considered helpful?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing edits (at least as a moderator?) one of the options is to delete the post.  The tooltip says that this will also "delete" the suggested edit.  Is this edit marked as helpful, non-helpful or just disintegrated into nothingness?

Comment: Ohhhh whe did they add that button? And what happens if I click it on a tag wiki edit?

Comment: @animuson http://www.brisbanetimes.com.au/ffximage/2008/09/24/470x400planet_collide,0.jpg

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug. The queues are designed to be streamlined towards their own tasks, deleting the post is not something that should come in the normal reviewing of edits.

In addition, actually using the button pops up a confirmation dialog that has no text in it.

[image]